# How to get properly formatted test results with nunit constraints

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

My custom constraint collects messages about expected values and actual values. They are written to the 'MessageWriter' by overriding 'WriteDescriptionTo':

```
    public override void WriteDescriptionTo(MessageWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteExpectedValue(_expectedMessages);
        writer.WriteActualValue(_actualMessages);
    }
```

But in the test results all information is in the expected result:

> Expected: <
>   On item 2 expected: Expected Reversible: True
>   <>
>   On item 2 actual: Actual Reversible: False
>   >
>   But was: <UNSET>

NOTE: I fail in formatting the text here, it refuses to use respect my newlines. So here's a screenshot of the result text:

[image: nunit refuses to format test results correctly]

The "But was:" part remains <UNSET>

So how to get the actual text to the right spot?

It's not a huge problem, just really annoying that I seem to be using the right method but it won't work, even seems like a bug in nunit.

Comment: Why do you refuse to believe that `_actualMessages` is indeed `UNSET` a.k.a. not assigned? Check your code paths whether its set or not.

Comment: I checked that with the debugger and _expectedMessages and _actualMessages each only have the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I checked the source of NUnit. The *actual* line is **always** generated by the framework, whether or not you called `WriteActualValue` before.

Instead you should set the `actual` field of your custom constraint (inherited from `Constraint`) to your `_actualMessages` stuff (or you refactor your code to live without `_actualMessages` at all). This should bring your expected output.